# Adding dot config and debugging utilities to a docker instance

Tags: bash, docker

I've got a project where a Flask server is run as a docker service via docker-compose (other elements like other API servers, the DB, are modeled as separate services in Docker Compose).

In my dev flow there are times when it's useful for me to drop into a bash shell (via `docker exec -it <container_id> bash`) and do some debugging like poking around at the files in there, take some logs and write some quick scripts to do some transformations on them, etc. In these scenarios I find it would be useful to have things like my bashrc, bash_profile, and various scripts which I find useful to do this sort of thing inside the docker container.

Is there an easy way to package these things and inject them into a (running) container? I'd prefer to not have these various debug things in the main Dockerfile which is shared.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `Dockerfile.debug` which uses the actual `Dockerfile`-image as base. Then grab your bash files into that.

Alternatively, locate the relevant container directory in `/var/lib/docker` and just put the files there (on the host). A trick to find the correct onion slice is to exec into the container, do a `touch hello.txt`, and then just `find` that file on the host.

Comment: Would the Dockerfile.debug get picked up automatically? Is there docs on that?

Comment: Added some clarifications about running in docker-compose, it looks like I can override things like the Dockerfile via a custom compose file that adds to the existing one. Seems then I could specify a Dockerfile.debug as the override.